# simple jquery on image click gallery

Tags: jquery, image, gallery

I have simple gallery and when I click on image (size is defined in img tag) it should open it on center of screen and resize it to its original dimensions or some other defined. Now it just centers the image.
Thank you!

```
    <style>
#img-cover {
    position: absolute;
    display:none;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:black;
    opacity:0.6;
    z-index:9998;
}
#img-container {
    position:fixed;
    display:none;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-50px;
    margin-left:-100px;
    z-index:9999;
}
</style>

    <script>
            $('.img').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#img-cover').fadeIn();
    var img = $(this);
    $('#img-container').html(img.clone())
        .css({
        'margin-top': '-' + img.height() / 2 + 'px',
            'margin-left': '-' + img.width() / 2 + 'px'
    }).fadeIn();
});

$('#img-cover').on('click', function () {
    $('#img-cover').fadeOut();
    $('#img-container').fadeOut();
});
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .clone() has side effect. It produces elements with duplicate id attributes.
Id attributes are supposed to be unique.
Let's suppose you want to show users the images in the gallery.
The web page will display the small size images. When the user clicks on an image, the page will display the original size image. Demo2 do just that. Enjoy!

```
//
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
index.html
-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style type="text/css">
        #img-cover {
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: black;
            opacity: 0.6;
            z-index: 9998;
        }
        #img-container {
            position: fixed;
            display: none;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-top: -50px;
            margin-left: -100px;
            z-index: 9999;
        }
        #frame {
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: gold;
            opacity: 0.6;
            z-index: 9997;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="pathto/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.img4').on('click', function (e) {
               $('#frame').fadeIn('slow');
               $('#img-cover').fadeOut('slow');
               $('#img-container').fadeOut('slow');
            });
           $('img').on('click', function (e) {
               $('#img-cover').fadeIn();
               var img = $(this);
               $('#img-container').html(img.clone())
                   .css({
                   'margin-top': '-' + img.height()/2 + 'px',
                   'margin-left': '-' + img.width()/2 + 'px'
                }).fadeIn();
            });
            $('#img-cover').on('click', function (){
                $('#img-cover').fadeOut();
                $('#img-container').fadeOut();
            });
            $('#btnReset').on('click', function (){
                $('#frame').fadeOut();
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="img2">
        <h1>Image Gallery2.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="img3">
        Demo1
        <img src="pathto/images/myimage.jpg" height="110" width="110" alt="MyImage" />
    </div>
    <div id="img-container">
        Image container.
    </div>
    <div id="img-cover">
        Image cover.
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="img4">
        Demo2
        <img src="pathto/images/myimage.jpg" height="110" width="110" alt="MyImage" />
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="frame">
        Demo3
        <img src="pathto/images/myimage.jpg" alt="MyImage" />
        <hr>
        <input type="button" id="btnReset" value="Reset" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
//
```